# Error while creating a shape in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, shapes

I am trying to create shape on a range specified in a cell A1. For Example if text in Cell A1 is `"B5:D7"` then macros creates a shape on `B5:D7` using the following code:

```
Sub CreateShape()
    Dim myRng       As Range
    Dim sh          As Object
    Dim rngPath     As String

    rngPath = Range("A1").Value

    Set myRng = Range(rngPath)
    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 1, 1, 1, 1)

    With sh
        .Left = myRng.Left
        .Top = myRng.Top
        .Width = myRng.Width
        .Height = myRng.Height
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With

End Sub
```

but this give an error in case entire row or entire column or big range like `"B2:B1048576"` is provided. Can anyone please help me in modifying this code?

I have already tried using `ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Height` and `Worksheet.UsedRange.Height` in both cases I get a smaller box and it doesn't represents the complete range.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error would occur on this line:

```
.Height = myRng.Height
```

The problem is that you try to set the `Height` property with a value that surpasses the max through VBA.

Both the `Height` and `Width` properties of a shape have a max of `169056` points; a point equals [1/72inch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#point), so the max would equal about 2348inch or 5965.23cm.

As long as the range you provide will not surpass that height or width, the code will NOT error out. As soon as the range provided is larger, the code WILL error out.

**Note:** You can manually drag the shape larger than you can set the property through VBA. But doing so will not increase the dimensions under the Format tab > Size!